# GUI in Python doesn't work reliably with Arduino without time.sleep(3)

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino

I have built a small Python GUI that turns the LED 13 on the Arduino on and off. However, it only seems to work reliably if there is a timeout (`time.sleep(3)`) in the Python script. To me, this `time.sleep(3)` does the trick. I dont' think that there is another problem. Can anyone explain me why this timeout is necessary? I would like to have the code run reliably and smoothly without this timeout!

Here is the python code:

```
import wx
import time
import serial

def arduino_on(event):
    byte = 102
    out = serial.Serial("COM5", 9600)
    time.sleep(3)
    out.write(chr(byte))
    print("I received: ")
    print(chr(byte))
    print("LED should be on!\n")

def arduino_off(event):
    byte = 97
    out = serial.Serial("COM5", 9600)
    time.sleep(3)
    out.write(chr(byte))
    print("I received: ")
    print(chr(byte))
    print("LED should be off!\n")

app = wx.PySimpleApp()

frame1 = wx.Frame(None, -1, size=(240, 100))
frame1.SetTitle("Arduino Communicator v. 0.1")
button1 = wx.Button(frame1, -1, "LED On")
button2 = wx.Button(frame1, -1, "LED off")
button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, arduino_on)
button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, arduino_off)
sizer1 = wx.GridBagSizer(vgap = 3, hgap = 3)
sizer1.Add(button1, (1,0), (1, 1), wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
sizer1.Add(button2, (1,1), (1, 1), wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
frame1.SetSizer(sizer1)
frame1.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

And here is the Arduino Code:

```
int led = 13;
int incomingByte = 0; // for incoming serial data

void setup() {
  // initialize serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); 
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  // read the incoming byute
  incomingByte = Serial.read();
  // say what you got:
  Serial.print("I received: " );
  Serial.print(incomingByte, DEC);
  Serial.print(" ");

  if (incomingByte > 100) {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    Serial.println("LED on! ");
  } else if (incomingByte <= 100) {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW); 
    Serial.println("LED off! ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Just open the serial port once and communicate over that established connection. This way you just have to wait once for the arduino to reset. Flush after writing.  Then you'll have to actually read the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because, whenever the Arduino gets a serial connection, it resets itself and then has to restart the sketch. This can take a second or two.

Like mentioned, it'd be best to just use *one* serial connection for the whole script. Here's what it would look like:

```
import wx
import time
import serial
out = serial.Serial("COM5", 9600)

def arduino_on(event):
    byte = 102
    time.sleep(3)
    out.write(chr(byte))
    print("I received: ")
    print(chr(byte))
    print("LED should be on!\n")


def arduino_off(event):
    byte = 97
    time.sleep(3)
    out.write(chr(byte))
    print("I received: ")
    print(chr(byte))
    print("LED should be off!\n")

app = wx.PySimpleApp()

frame1 = wx.Frame(None, -1, size=(240, 100))
frame1.SetTitle("Arduino Communicator v. 0.1")
button1 = wx.Button(frame1, -1, "LED On")
button2 = wx.Button(frame1, -1, "LED off")
button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, arduino_on)
button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, arduino_off)
sizer1 = wx.GridBagSizer(vgap = 3, hgap = 3)
sizer1.Add(button1, (1,0), (1, 1), wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
sizer1.Add(button2, (1,1), (1, 1), wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
frame1.SetSizer(sizer1)
frame1.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: The arduino does not reset itself when it gets a serial connection.

Comment: @Sibster that's not true, except for the Leonardo. http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection